# Are there any possible reasons for a decreased view rate if nothing on the site has been changed?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analystics says that over the last 4 complete weeks (e.g., may 21 to june 16), the average was ~90 views/day. For the last week, the average is 17.5/views day. Nothing on the site appears to of changed. There is no advertising. Could there be more to this than random flucation?

Comment: Maybe they updated their algorithms to weed out sites with extreme HTML errors. (The bottom half of your page). You're sure nothing's changed in the code from before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer - someone added a .haccess file that redirected people visiting the page from places outside of Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be:

1. The fact that nothing has changed could be the problem. Interest might be dying out in some of your pages.
2. Google could have updated it's algorithms. Check [webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to see if you have any errors. Also, if you were using any black hat techniques, Google could be lowering your ranking because of that.
3. You could have some change that you don't know about, like a server error. Check to make sure that isn't happening.